# query one sheet based on cell in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

My master data sheet is named MASTER.
In my sheet named PRINT I want to be able to use a date picker, or somehow be prompted for a date, and then a Query pulls data from Master where date selected matches dates in MASTER column B. I have tried the following Query statement but it will only work if I change both sheets Date columns to TEXT format. I need to keep my date formats as is. If all that makes sense, I would really appreciate some help. My end goal is I just want a huge list of fabrication jobs, listed by date, to be queried and pulled to another sheet for printing. Leaving all Master data in tact and where the PRINT sheet can simply have a date change done by any user and get the list they need.

```
=Query(MASTER!A:P,ʺselect * where B ='ʺ&A2&ʺ'ʺ,0)
```

The above Query is on my TEST sheet where I have a date picker in column A2

Comment: Here is shared sheet - Note that the date format I am using on MASTER is what I need and it doesn't seem to impact the other query being done on the CAPACITIES sheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goG0TS1_2jwlGRetREYNRVk-Q6TEy3iWG_5VXFoZlus/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=Query(MASTER!A:P,"select * where B =date"""&text(A2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&""" ",0)
```

and see if that works for you ?

Comment: That works perfect except there are some strange unfamiliar dates being put in columnA that I can't figure out where they are coming from. Does that make sense? I don't have enough credits to send a screenshot.

Comment: I know it has to do with the numbers I am using in colA that are "sequence" numbers I am utilizing, but not sure how to prevent that from being converted to dates on the query output. Sorry for so many replies

Comment: Nevermind, I just hid columnA on query output as not needed. Your code worked PERFECTLY and thank you so very much.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. For the 'numbers' did you check if everyting (including the col with dates from the output) is formatted as date ?

Comment: JPV, could I impose on you one more time? How do I add a second criteria to match. I want to Type in "xyz" on PRINTS cell B3 so that if date and cell B3 matches colF on the MASTER sheet then pull that data. I am trying to match date and Sales Rep criteria for another sheet named "UnPro'd". https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goG0TS1_2jwlGRetREYNRVk-Q6TEy3iWG_5VXFoZlus/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try: =Query(MASTER!A:P,"select * where B =date"""&text(B2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and F = '"&C2&"' ",0)